# Transform js file into json file with laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I have a .js file with key-value pairs like this:

es.js

```
export default 
{
    currency:"Dinero",
    void:"Vacio",
}
```

And I want to transform that file into a .json file.

es.json

```
{
    "currency" : "Dinero",
    "void" : "Vacio",
}
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: you want to read the file, and convert, change the extension, all in laravel?

Comment: Yes, I want to create a new json file from the js file

Comment: sorry late.^https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/transform-js-file-into-json-file-with-laravel and use JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE on encode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i would do this:

-i open the file ($handle = fopen('yourjavascriptfile.js', 'r');)

-i read every line until i find the obj opening ( { )

-now every non-empty line is pushed in a php associative array (logic is up to you)

-when you find the } closing you are done.

-you create a json file (could be, Storage::disk('public')->put('yourjson.json', json_encode($associativearray));)

-you delete the initial js file